# localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 501 - Tried switch environment but still not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-500

I tried switch the environment, hosting is running in php ver 7.3, even no error code showing. i turned the error switch in php selector but still i can't find any solution.
i just switch the url and DB details because i want to run the app in another domain also.
here the code of index.php:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }
        else
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
        break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1);
```

The CI_Controller Code Is:

```
<?php

class Cl_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        /*group by issue skip*/
        $this->db->query("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));");
        $file_pointer = str_rot13('nffrgf/oyhrvzc/ERFG_NCV.wfba');
        if (file_exists($file_pointer)) {
            $file_content = file_get_contents($file_pointer);

            $json_data = json_decode($file_content, true);

            $installation_date = $json_data['date'];

            $meta_date = date("Y-m-d", filectime($file_pointer));

            if ($installation_date != $meta_date) {
                echo $this->load->view('errors/html/REST_API_JSON.php', '', TRUE);
                die();
            }
        }else {
            echo $this->load->view('errors/html/REST_API_JSON.php', '', TRUE);
            die();
        }

        $file_pointer_i = str_rot13('nffrgf/vafgnyyngvba_vasbezngvba/ERFG_NCV_V.wfba');
        if (file_exists($file_pointer_i)) {
            $file_content_i = file_get_contents($file_pointer_i);
            $json_data_i = json_decode($file_content_i, true);
            $installation_url_  = str_rot13($json_data_i['installation_url']);
            $installation_url = str_replace('www.','',str_replace('https://','',str_replace('','',str_replace('http://','',$installation_url_))));
            $separate_url = explode('/', $installation_url);
            $installation_url = str_replace('www.','',str_replace('https:','',str_replace('','',str_replace('http://','',(isset($separate_url[0]) && $separate_url[0]?$separate_url[0]:$installation_url_)))));
            $server_url = str_replace('www.','',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

            if (str_rot13($server_url) != 'ybpnyubfg') {
                if ($installation_url != ($server_url)) {
                    echo $this->load->view('errors/html/REST_API_JSONS.php', '', TRUE);
                    die();
                }
            }else{
                $installation_url = str_replace('www.','',str_replace('https:','',str_replace('/','',str_replace('http://','',$installation_url_))));
                $first_segment = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $installation_url_new = str_replace('www.','',str_replace('https:','',str_replace('/','',str_replace('http://','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$first_segment[1]))));

                if ($installation_url != ($installation_url_new)) {
                    echo $this->load->view('errors/html/REST_API_JSONS.php', '', TRUE);
                    die();
                }
            }
        }else {
            echo $this->load->view('errors/html/REST_API_JSONS.php', '', TRUE);
            die();
        }

    }

    public function allUserList($param){
        if ($param == 1) {
            if (file_exists('assets/blueimp/REST_API.json')) {
                unlink('assets/blueimp/REST_API.json');
            }
        }else if($param == 2){
            $path = "assets/blueimp/REST_API.json";
            $handle = fopen($path, "w");

            if (!file_exists('assets/blueimp/REST_API.json')) {
                if ($handle) {
                    $content = '{ "date":"'. date('Y-m-d') .'" }';
                    // Write the file
                    if(fwrite($handle,$content)) {
                        @chmod($output_path,0644);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific where are you setting your environment type? Have you tired debug $_SERVER['CI_ENV']? What is inside?

Comment: I've not tried to debug $_SERVER['CI_ENV']. I changed the environment in define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
switch (ENVIRONMENT)

Comment: and config>database.php file

Comment: So, when you debug (or display via var_dump) $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] what can you see?

Comment: Also check your web server's error log to see if there are any useful error messages in there.